# Problemas para refrescar imagen de una modal

Tags: php, html

Estimados tengo una aplicacion que muestra una imagen en una modal, la problematica es que siempre me muestra la ultima imagen que tome.
Djunto trozo de mi codigo.
Slds.

```
    <div class="" >

        <img src="logo300.png" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Responsive image">
    </div>  
        <div class="container" align="center">
            <b> <h2 align="center" class="">BANDEJA ENTRADA</h2></b>
        </div>

            <div class="container-fluid">

                <ul class="tabs">
                    <li><a href="#tab1"><span class="fa fa-table"></span><span class="tab-text">Sin Procesar</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tab2"><span class="fa fa-table"></span><span class="tab-text">Procesados</span></a></li>
                </ul>

                <div class="secciones" >
                    <article id="tab1">

                         <table id="user_data" class="table  table-striped  table-hover">    
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                      <th>Accion</th>
                                      <th>Imagen</th>
                                      <th>Id</th>
                                      <th>Rut</th>
                                      <th>Cod. Proyecto</th>
                                      <th>Payroll</th>
                                      <th>Nombre</th>
                                      <th>Cliente</th>
                                      <th>Supervisor</th>
                                      <th>Enviada</th>
                                      <th>Proc.</th>
                                      <th>F.Proc.</th>
                                      <th>Observaciones</th>

                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                         </table>
                    </article>
                    <article id="tab2">
                        <div>
                                <br>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="input-daterange">
                                        <div class="col-md-2">
                                             <input type="text" name="start_date" id="start_date" class="form-control" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-2">
                                             <input type="text" name="end_date" id="end_date" class="form-control" />
                                        </div>      
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                         <input type="button" name="search" id="search" value="Buscar" class="btn btn-success active" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <br>

                             <table id="Procesados" class="table  table-striped  table-hover">  
                                    <thead>
                                     <tr>
                                      <th>Imagen</th>
                                                              <th >Id</th>
                                                              <th>Rut</th>
                                                              <th>Cod. Proyecto</th>
                                                              <th>Payroll</th>
                                                              <th>Nombre</th>
                                                              <th>Cliente</th>
                                                              <th>Supervisor</th>
                                                              <th>Enviada</th>
                                                              <th>Proc.</th>
                                                              <th>F.Proc.</th>
                                                              <th>Observaciones</th>


                                     </tr>
                                    </thead>
                             </table>

                         </div>



             </article>
        </div>  

     </div>


            <div id="userModal" class="modal fade">

                 <div class="modal-dialog">
                <form method="post" id="user_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <div class="modal-content">

             <div class="modal-body">
                <label>Observaciones</label>
                <input type="text" name="Observaciones" id="Observaciones" class="form-control" />
                                    <br>
                                    <label>Payroll</label>
                <input type="text" name="Payroll" id="Payroll" class="form-control" />
                                    <br>

                <label>Imagen</label>


                <br>

                                    <div ID="ngy2p" data-nanogallery2='{
                                                <?php
                                                $ruta=$_SESSION['Ru']; 
                                                $dire=explode('/', $ruta, -1);
                                                 $nombreimagen=$_SESSION['im'];
                                                echo '"itemsBaseURL": "http://localhost/imagenes/'.$dire[2].'/",';
                                                ?>     

                                                "thumbnailWidth": "200",
                                                "thumbnailHeight":  200,
                                                "thumbnailAlignment": "center",
                                                "galleryDisplayMode": "moreButton"
                                              }'>
                                      <!--      <a href="103415532697252866333314592037090581.JPG" data-ngthumb="103415532697252866333314592037090581.jpg"></a>-->
                                              <a href="<?php echo $nombreimagen; ?>"><img data-ngthumb="<?php echo $nombreimagen; ?>"/></a>

                                              <?php

                                                 $nombreimagen=$_SESSION['im'];
                                               // echo "<a href='".$nombreimagen."'data-ngthumb='".$nombreimagen."'></a>";
                                                 unset($_SESSION['im']);  


                                              ?>
                                               <img src="http://localhost/imagenes/<?php echo  $dire[2]."/".$nombreimagen;?>" width=100 height=100>


                                    </div>



             <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id" />
                <input type="hidden" name="operation" id="operation" />
                <input type="submit" name="action" id="action" class="btn btn-success" value="Add" />
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">&times;Close</button>
             </div>
             </div>
             </form>
             </div>
            </div>

             <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/nanogallery2/dist/jquery.nanogallery2.min.js"></script>    

            <script src="bootstrap-3.3.7/js/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
            <script src="bootstrap-3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <script src="plugins/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
            <script src="plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

            <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>

            <script src="js/main.js"></script>
            <script src="js/functions.js"></script>
            <script src="js/sweetalert.min.js"></script>



<link href="https://unpkg.com/nanogallery2/dist/css/nanogallery2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/nanogallery2/dist/jquery.nanogallery2.min.js"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
            $(document).ready(function(){

                    var dataTable = $('#user_data').DataTable({
                        "language": {"url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.16/i18n/Spanish.json"},
                        "responsive": true,
                        "processing":true,
                        "serverSide":true,
                        "bServerSide": true,
                        "lengthChange": false,
                        paginate:false,
                        info: false,
                        "order":[],
                        "autoWidth": true,
                        "destroy":true,
                        "ajax":{
                               "url":"fetch",
                               "type":"POST"
                        },
                        "columnDefs":[
                                    {
                                            "targets":[0],
                                            "orderable":false,
                                            "bSortable": true,
                                            "bServerSide": true

                                    }
                        ]


                    }); 
                    setInterval( function () {
                            dataTable.ajax.reload();
                            }, 30000 );
                    $('.input-daterange').datepicker({
                        "locale": {
                        "separator": " - ",
                        "applyLabel": "Aplicar",
                        "cancelLabel": "Cancelar",
                        "fromLabel": "Desde",
                        "toLabel": "Hasta",
                        "customRangeLabel": "Custom",
                        "daysOfWeek": [
                            "Do",
                            "Lu",
                            "Ma",
                            "Mi",
                            "Ju",
                            "Vi",
                            "Sa"
                        ],
                        "monthNames": [
                        "Enero",
                        "Febrero",
                        "Marzo",
                        "Abril",
                        "Mayo",
                        "Junio",
                        "Julio",
                        "Agosto",
                        "Septiembre",
                        "Octubre",
                        "Noviembre",
                        "Diciembre"
                        ],
                        "firstDay": 1
                        },

                        format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
                        autoclose: true

                     });

                    fetch_data('no');

                    function fetch_data(is_date_search, start_date='', end_date='')
                         {
                        var dataTable = $('#Procesados').DataTable({

                        "Destroy":true,

                        "language":{
                           "lengthMenu":"Mostrar _MENU_ registros por página.",
                           "zeroRecords": "Lo sentimos. No se encontraron registros.",
                                 "info": "Mostrando página _PAGE_ de _PAGES_",
                                 "infoEmpty": "No hay registros aún.",
                                 "infoFiltered": "(filtrados de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
                                 "search" : "Buscar",
                                 "LoadingRecords": "Cargando ...",
                                 "Processing": "Procesando...",
                                 "SearchPlaceholder": "Comience a teclear...",
                                 "paginate": {
                         "previous": "Anterior",
                         "next": "Siguiente" 
                         }
                        },
                         paginate:false,
                         info: false,

                        scrollCollapse: true,

                        "bFilter": true, 


                        "processing" : true,

                        "serverSide" : true,
                        "sort": true,
                        "order" : [],
                        "dom": 'lBfrtip',
                        "buttons": [
                         {
                         extend: 'collection',
                         text: 'Exportar',
                         buttons: [
                         'copy',
                         'excel',
                         'csv'

                         ]
                         }
                         ],

                         "responsive": true,
                         "bServerSide": true,
                         "lengthChange": true,       
                         "ajax" : {
                            url:"ajax",
                            type:"POST",
                            data:{
                                is_date_search:is_date_search, start_date:start_date, end_date:end_date
                             }
                         }   
                 },
                     );

                 setInterval( function () {
                            dataTable.ajax.reload();
                            }, 30000 );

             }


             $('#search').click(function(){
              var start_date = $('#start_date').val();
              var end_date = $('#end_date').val();
              if(start_date != '' && end_date !='')
              {

               fetch_data('yes', start_date, end_date);
              }
              else
              {

              swal("Por favor seleccione las fechas");

              }
             }); 

                    $(document).on('submit', '#user_form', function(event){
                            event.preventDefault();
                            var Observaciones = $('#Observaciones').val();
                            var Payroll = $('#Payroll').val();

                            if(Observaciones != '' || Payroll != '')
                            {
                                   $.ajax({
                                            url:"insert",
                                            method:'POST',
                                            data:new FormData(this),
                                            contentType:false,
                                            processData:false,
                                            success:function(data)
                                            {

                                                    swal("Asistencia", "Datos Actualizados:)", "success");
                                                    $('#user_form')[0].reset();
                                                    $('#userModal').modal('hide');
                                                    dataTable.ajax.reload();


                                            }
                                    });

                            }
                            else
                            {

                                     swal("Asistencia", "Favor Ingresar por lo menos un dato", "success");
                            }
                    });

                    $(document).on('click', '.update', function(){

                           var user_id = $(this).attr("id");
                       //    document.write(user_id); 


                            $.ajax({
                                    url:"fetch_single.php",
                                    method:"POST",
                                    data:{user_id:user_id},
                                    dataType:"json",
                                    success:function(data)
                                    {


                                            $('#userModal').modal('show');

                                            $('#Observaciones').val(data.Observaciones);
                                            $('#Payroll').val(data.Payroll);
                                            $('#image').val(data.image);
                                            $('.modal-title').text("Edit User");
                                            $('#user_id').val(user_id);
                                            $('#user_uploaded_image').html(data.user_image);
                                            $('#user_uploaded_image2').val(data.user_image);
                                            $('#action').val("Edit");
                                            $('#operation').val("Edit");

                                    }
                            });


                    });




                });
            </script>
```

Comment: Simple.. al cerrar el modal refresca la página, colocale esta función al botón que cierra el modal. location.reload();

Comment: Si pero tampoco funciona, de hecho sucede que a la primera vez no aparece ninguna imagen pero cuando refresco la pagina y vuelvo a presionar el botón para mostrar la modal me muestra la ultima que accedí.

Comment: Si pero tampoco funciona, de hecho sucede que a la primera vez no aparece ninguna imagen pero cuando refresco la pagina y vuelvo a presionar el botón para mostrar la modal me muestra la ultima que accedí.

Comment: Disculpa soy aprendiz y no se como realizar lo que me explicas con el getdate()

Answer (score 0):

El problema es de cache del navegador intenta concatenar un getdate() despues de la imagen

http://localhost/imagenes/prueba.png?20190402